# How can I change my primary Gmail address (remove the dots)

Tags: gmail

My Gmail address is `john.doe@gmail.com`. I am thinking about removing the dot and use `johndoe@gmail.com` as my primary mail address. I know that I already receive mails which are addressed to `johndoe@gmail.com` since Gmail ignores the dots. Still, I want my primary address to be `johndoe@gmail.com`, meaning that my outgoing mail should be seen as being sent by `johndoe@gmail.com`.

I know that there is the setting "send mail as" where I can configure a secondary email address as `johndoe@gmail.com`, but this does not satisfy me since in the email source code there will be the fields "return-path" and "sender" which still hold `john.doe@gmail.com`. I would like to be able to send mails without `john.doe@gmail.com` appearing in the source code of sent mail.

I think this can only be achieved by changing my primary mail-address from `john.doe@gmail.com` to `johndoe@gmail.com`. Since I cannot register a new Gmail address with my preferred name, because Gmail ignores dots, I do not know how to do this.

**ANSWER HERE:** http://productforums.google.com/forum/#!mydiscussions/gmail/ax6WMJB4gkA

Comment: hm not really a duplicate, because as pointed out i know the feature called "send mail as". but since this does not satisfy me (for the reasons mentioned above) i asked for another solution. please see the same thread i created in the official google forums for further info: http://productforums.google.com/forum/#!mydiscussions/gmail/ax6WMJB4gkA

Comment: Just as a comment the original question added a *ANSWER HERE* legend that basically leads to a post saying that it is *not* possible. I think it is possible, follow @nitrl answer, or the one linked at the top.

Answer (score 7):

I believe [this](http://www.nerdydork.com/gmail-addresses-ignore-dots.html) will answer your question:

> If you created your account with a dot in your username and you wish
>   you hadn’t, you can change your ‘Reply-to address.’ To change your
>   reply-to address:
>
> 1. Click ‘Settings’ at the top of any Gmail page.
> 2. Enter your username@gmail.com without a dot in the ‘Reply-to address’ field.
> 3. Click ‘Save Changes.’
>
> When you log in to Gmail, you need to enter any dots that were
>   originally defined as part of your username.

Comment: This doesn't work for me. When I send mail to `*@yahoo.com`, the raw message doesn't contain my `undotted@gmail.com`. Other aliases do work. Frustrating.

Comment: I just want to add that in addition to changing the 'Reply-to Address' you would also need to change the 'Send mail As' to the un-dotted address. Changing the 'Send Mail As' is where you find the option to change the 'Reply-to', but perhaps not everyone realized that you need to change both in order to... change both of these

Answer (score -2):

I'm afraid your only option is to register a new Gmail (Google) account, and forward your e-mails between them.

From [Google Help](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/8158?hl=en):

> You can change the name that's linked to your email address, but not the address itself.

Comment: Although in the OP's case they won't be able to register a new account with the desired gmail address since gmail will see it as already taken (since it is perceived to be the same as their current address).

Comment: yes, thats true. i wont be able to register a new gmail-account with my desired name, since it's already taken, meaning that "namewithdots" is the same as "namewithoutdots". but thank you all for your help/infos.